# picture showing up small

Tags: magento-1.9

why can this be happening? it seems like i have space for the picture to be larger, and if i click on it it does open up pretty large.

so why such a small preview?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please post your code

Comment: i don't have any code, i'm using it the way it was written. I'm using Amasty extension though, could it be that they coded something that makes it look this way?

Comment: check in admin have any configuration for width and height?

Comment: I did and tried changing them and stays the same. I have a few ideas, will try them out and will post back. I thought maybe this was a known issues. Thank you

Comment: @lalachka My guess would be that you don't have a base image set. The little 'More Views' image is there because it's not 'Excluded'. So within the manage products page for that product, check the image settings. Set one to base. If you click exclude, then the small preview disappears.

Comment: i do, added pic to original, thank you though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, dumb question, the Amasty extension had weird settings for images and it was controlling the image size